# How can we prove by technique ε−δ, that $ \lim_{x\to 0} \sin\frac1x$ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

How can we prove by technique $ \varepsilon$-$\delta $, that this limit does not exist?

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin\frac1x$$

Comment: What have you tried? You'll have to show what you've done to get the answer here.

Comment: In order to use $\epsilon,\delta$ to show that a limit does **not** exist, you have to have a very clear understanding of the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of a limit actually existing.  Then, you have to understand how to negate that definition.  For example, suppose that you choose the fixed value of $\epsilon = (1/4)$.  Then, you would have to show that no matter how small $\delta > 0$ is chosen, there will be two values $x_1, x_2$ in the neighbor hood of radius $\delta$ around the pertinent value $x$ such that $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| > 2\epsilon = (1/2)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: For any $\delta > 0$ there are values of $x$ such that $|x| < \delta$ and $f(x) = 1, 0,$ and $-1$

Comment: For any $L$ you have that $|f(x_1) - L| + |f(x_2) - L| \geq |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| = 2\epsilon$.  This implies that regardless of the value of $L$, one of the two values $|f(x_1) - L|$ or $|f(x_2) - L|$ will be greater than $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Define $f(x)=sin(1/x)$. You could take $\epsilon=1/2$ and observe $f\big{(}B(0,\delta)\setminus\{0\}\big{)}=[-1,1]$ for any $\delta>0$. Does this help?

Comment: Just as a heads-up since you are new, it is discouraged to answer problem solving questions (PSQs) with little to no effort shown.

Comment: Please more guide.

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know. Should I erase my answer? It is not the whole answer though, it requires some understanding of $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments to get the hint.

Comment: @H.... Struggle a little bit with the problem before asking for more guide! :) Tell us what've you tried.

Comment: Given any $\delta>0$, do you think you can find a subset $A\subseteq f^{-1}([-1,1])\cap (0,\delta)$ such that $f(A)=[-1,1]$?

Comment: Thanks for guide. The problem  solved.